# Text resize while maintaining multiline

Tags: flutter

Code:

```
              Container(
                    constraints:
                         BoxConstraints(maxHeight: mediaQuery.height*0.1, minHeight: mediaQuery.height*0.05),
                    child: Text(
                      output['title'],
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                  ),
```

As the screen won't be scrollable, I determine the max height for the container. With the current text, it takes 3 lines with the font size 16. If its bigger, won't appear. How to resize the `fontSize` if the text is bigger while mantaining multine text? Have already tried `FittedBox` then `fit` but it takes only one line

Answer (score 0):

You can check [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text).

Demo

```dart
AutoSizeText(
  'The text to display',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
  maxLines: 3,
)
```